# Why is this sentence structure correct?

Tags: noun-phrases

I happened to see an article talking about mental health with the title:

> 10 things your mental health is more important than.

There they listed the 10 things which are less important than our mental health. The sentence structure seems somewhat strange or at least I am not familiar with structures like these. Could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "10 thing**s**"? There is supposed to be a rule that you don't end a sentence with a preposition, like "This is the house I live in". Many people think the rule is nonsense, but I do agree with you that this sentence sounds strange. They could have said "10 things that are less important than your mental health". See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: It's not a sentence. 'Five things that are more important than money.' / 'Four things you should avoid.' /  '3 places to visit before you die.' / '10 things that are brilliant.' / 'The man in the street.' _None of them an independent clause._ **Contrast** 'Here are 10 things your mental health is more important than.' _But as Kate says, ending a string with 'than' is at worst quirky._

Comment: Well, it does violate the rule that you should never use a preposition to end a sentence with.  But then it's not a sentence, just a caption.